How to authenticate Azure ArmClient with SAS?
How do I authenticate ArmClient that requres Azure.Core.TokenCredential as parameter having only SAS token string constructed like this?
string sasToken = $"SharedAccessSignature sr={url}&sig={sig}&se={exp}&skn={sharedAccessKeyName}";


What are you trying to do?

I am trying to use Azure .NET SDK's ArmClient to manage queues in Azure Service Bus and I would like to connect using SAS

You will not be able to use SAS token with ARM client. AFAIK, ARM client requires Azure AD token.

There is also ServiceBusAdministrationClient that seems to be able to do what I want but not sure why there are two APIs

There is a long story behind ServiceBusAdministrationClient thing (there's a pretty long thread on GitHub regarding this that I am not able to find now)  but it is suffice to say that you can use SAS token with this client to manage your Service Bus Queues.

I think you are talking about the community "resistance" mentioned here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk/issues/1360

Thanks. No that was not it. It was a pretty big thread on GitHub where Service Bus team initially refused to implement ServiceBusAdministrationClient kind of functionality.

Not possible. There was community discussion about this. See story
